# Redirect Silex Boilerplate in Storyblok Project

Tags: redirect, silex, boilerplate, storyblok

How can I add redirects to my Storyblok project when it is using the Silex Boilerplate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect to another page by returning a RedirectResponse response, which you can create by calling the redirect method:

```
app->get('/{{entry_path}}', function () use ($app) {
    return $app->redirect('/{{exit_path}}');
});
```

http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/usage.html#redirects

When you want to delegate the rendering to another controller, without a round-trip to the browser (as for a redirect), use an internal sub-request (Don't use this if you really want to redirect your page). We provide such an *forward* in the `app.php` for the `/home` slug already, so `/home` page would be accessible on `/` without redirecting but doing a subrequest.